# Tracking the target URLs for all clicks on a page

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is there a way to capture all click events that result in going to another URL - whether in the same window or a new one?

I'd like to capture the destination URLs of all clicked elements on a given page. The content of this page is dynamic and I don't have total control over all of the content, as I'm embedding social components such as Twitter/Facebook timelines.

Here's some pseudo code demonstrating what I'm trying to do:

```
$(document).click(function(element) {
    if(element.ClickIsGoingToGoToAnotherURL()) {
        url = element.DestinationURL;
        StoreUrlInDatabase(url);
    }
});
```

Comment: What do you consider as a `url` in this instance? Anything with a `http://` or `www.` prefix? If you had control over the URL items, you could just add a class to each element you consider to be a URL then bind to the click events for that class.

Comment: Or is it anything that is part of the `<a>` tag?

Comment: You could use something like `$(document).on('click', '.container a', function(element) { /* Log your stuff here */ }` so that all links within the container are included

Comment: You can't capture click events in cross-origin iframes, you can only capture where on the page the click occurred and then do some logic from there based on the size of the viewport etc to determine where they clicked at.

Comment: @AdamJeffers Ideally I'd capture any attempt to go to another url, which would include <a> tags and elements with an onclick event calling javascript that goes to another page. As a baby step, I'd be happy with just getting <a> tags. I'd consider any location value starting with http: or https: as URLs.

Answer (score -2):

This will work at the global scope.

```
var a = [];
$( "a" ).on( "click", function(event) {
      var href = $(this).attr('href');
      a.push(href);
});
```

Then access them all using a for loop on the `a` array. You can use HTML5 localStorage to store the array as a key/value pair and then then access the URL(s) you pushed into it from any page on the site.

Comment: How does this work with the OP's Twitter/Facebook embed's?

Comment: Push the array into HTMl5 localStorage and retrieve the array by key. You can store array in localStorage as they are treated like objects in JS. He can then access the links from any page on the site.

Comment: You cannot capture a click event inside of an iframe that's a 3rd party and doesn't have CORS enabled for your site. That won't work.

Comment: He is not capturing the click event in an iFrame. He is capturing it through the main window object. The social widgets have a variable in them that tells the generator what URL to use in the resulting iFrame. Just push the URL into that variable. I have done this before.

Comment: @DannyGibas Could you please clarify what you mean by "push the URL into that variable"?

Comment: Where you create your social widgets, pull the value from localStorage first - set that value to a var, and look at the markup for the widgets. In there will be the URL for the social media account you want to display. Just set that URL string to the URL stored in the localStorage key/pair variable and it should load the proper data into the widget iFrame that is generated.